# Cannot create service account on Windows 2008 R2 environment

Tags: active-directory, service-accounts

I have a domain where Domain & Forest functional levels are 2008 R2.
I can see on guides Managed service account are supported but I cannot create them.

I have tried:

```
New-ADServiceAccount -Name xxx_MSA -Enabled $true
New-ADServiceAccount -Server dc1 -DNSHostName xxx.xxx.gr -Name xxx_MSA -Enabled $true
```

and get the error

> "*The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist*",
>   **msDS-ManagedPasswordInterval**

I suppose the problem is the `kdsrootkey` but when I try to create it from the DC I get

> "*The term 'Add-KdsRootKey' is not recognized*".

I am missing something but cannot find what..

Comment: What happens if you run `Import-Module KDS` first?

Comment: After trying: 
Import-Module : The specified module 'KDS' was not loaded because no valid modu
le file was found in any module directory.